# Can people still find my wifi network even if I turn off SSID broadcasting?

Tags: wifi, ssid

My wifi router broadcasts my SSID but  I believe I can stop the SSID from being broadcast.  Were I to do so, would neighbors or anyone parked on the street fail to find my wifi and move on to the next guy?

Comment: It is more difficult to find your network, yes. but not impossible. If someone is looking for an easy network, then they won't "see" your network without hunting for it.